# Typescript redux-saga - compile error when Call api with call effect

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I'm trying to call a mock API and i got this error:
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CallEffectNamedFn<{ [x: string]: Func0; }, string>'.
Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type '{ context: { [x: string]: Func0; }; fn: string; }'.
Property 'context' is missing in type 'Promise'.

The version of redux-saga is: "^0.16.0"
tsConfig: 
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],

Here the mock API:

```
    getAllMembersAsync() : Promise<Program[]> {
    const promise : Promise<Array<Program>> = new Promise((resolve, reject) 
=> {
            var members : Array<Program>;

            members = ProgramsData.map((currentProgram) => {
                var program : Program = new Program();

                program.code = currentProgram.code;
                program.nom = currentProgram.nom;
                program.cours = currentProgram.cours;

                return program;
            });

            resolve(members);
        // });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

And here my saga:

```
import {call, put, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { receivedPrograms, FetchPrograms, FETCH_PROGRAMS } from 
'../actions/programActions';
import { Program } from '../model/program';
import programAPI from '../api/programAPI';

function* fetchPrograms(action: FetchPrograms) {
 let programs: Array<Program>;
 programs = yield call(programAPI.getAllMembersAsync());
 yield put(receivedPrograms(programs));
}
```

Can someone tell my what i'm not doing correctly ?

thanks alot guys !

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo... here the solution

```
programs = yield call(programAPI.getAllMembersAsync);
```